# Java filewriter in a loop

Tags: java, csv, filewriter

I'm just wondering if there's another way to do this in a loop?
Because I'm tired of putting all variable and pass it to the append method of the writer. Because I'm writing a output file that CSV.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        WoopTest program = new WoopTest();

        String a = "C:\\testfolder\\test\\testwrite.csv";
        String b = "1";
        String c = "2";
        String d = "3";
        String e = "4";
        String f = "5";
        String g = "6";
        String h = "7";

        printSomething(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h);

    }

    private static void printSomething(String filename, String input1, String input2, String input3, String input4
            , String input5, String input6, String input7) throws Exception{
        try{
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter((filename),true);

                writer.append(input1);
                writer.append(',');
                writer.append(input2);
                writer.append(',');
                writer.append(input3);
                writer.append(',');
                writer.append(input4);
                writer.append(',');
                writer.append(input5);
                writer.append(',');
                writer.append(input6);
                writer.append(',');
                writer.append(input7);
                writer.append('\n');

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Many different ways to do this, maybe consider an Array or an ArrayList or a specialised object class.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `array` of `String` to your `printSomething` method and then can add a loop to your method to iterate the array and appending the file.

Comment: How about the comma's?